# Changing Default of JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION while maintaining keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: java, swing, focus, joptionpane

Does anyone have experience with creating a `JOptionPane` such as the `YES_NO_OPTION` dialog and changing the default to "NO" while maintaining the keyboard shortcuts? I used an array of objects to populate the options of `{"YES", "NO"}` and then in the `JOptionPane.showOptionDialog` parameters I passed in those options. This works in changing the focus of the button, but removes the keyboard shortcuts for the buttons. Is there anyway to maintain the keyboard shortcuts while also changing focus? This is not a question of how to default to "NO" but rather how to maintain the keyboard shortcuts. The question "How to make JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog have No selected by default?" is asking about focus, no one ever answers how to maintain keyboard shortcuts.  Here is a snippet of the code...

```
Object[] options = {"YES", "NO"};
int choice = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Please choose yes/no", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE, null, options, options[1]);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog have No selected by default?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395707/how-to-make-joptionpane-showconfirmdialog-have-no-selected-by-default)

Comment: I can see how you think this is a duplicate, however my question specifically refers to the keyboard shortcuts, not the default focus. I have seen the question you posted as a possible duplicate and although people mention changing focus will eliminate keyboard shortcuts, no one seems to have a solution. Thanks @Omore

Comment: You want to draw only "NO" button in JOptionPane?

Comment: [for example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27379956/714968)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's any "easy" way to do this.  Instead, you're probably going to have to provide your own buttons.

So based on [JOptionPane Passing Custom Buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14591089/joptionpane-passing-custom-buttons/14591165#14591165) and [Disable ok button on JOptionPane.dialog until user gives an input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14334931/disable-ok-button-on-joptionpane-dialog-until-user-gives-an-input/14335083#14335083), you can provide your own `JButton`s preconfigured the way you want them, for example

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JButton btnYes = new JButton("Yes");
        btnYes.setMnemonic('s');
        btnYes.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JOptionPane pane = getOptionPane((JComponent)e.getSource());
                pane.setValue(JOptionPane.YES_OPTION);
            }
        });
        JButton btnNo = new JButton("No");
        btnNo.setMnemonic('o');
        btnNo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JOptionPane pane = getOptionPane((JComponent)e.getSource());
                pane.setValue(JOptionPane.NO_OPTION);
            }
        });
        JButton[] options = new JButton[] {btnYes, btnNo};

        JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(
                null, 
                "Help", 
                "More", 
                JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, 
                JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE, 
                null, options, btnYes);

    }

    protected static JOptionPane getOptionPane(JComponent parent) {
        JOptionPane pane = null;
        if (!(parent instanceof JOptionPane)) {
            pane = getOptionPane((JComponent)parent.getParent());
        } else {
            pane = (JOptionPane) parent;
        }
        return pane;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no straight forward way to do this.
my suggestion is to create your own dialog.
if you don't like that solution you can try by providing a JButton array instead of String array as options. those buttons should be constructed with mnemonics by your own to enable the shortcuts.

anyway this button construction logic is there in the `BasicOptionPaneUI.getButtons` method. go through this and its usage in `BasicOptionPaneUI.creatButtonArea` . then you may get a better way to do this